# Select and button elements mess up the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table and inside there is one *select* and one *button* element. I've set the select to take up all the width and it works. But now the cells don't take 50:50 space - instead the second td is always smaller. **This happens only when I have select element in table, otherwise not.**
 *Also, The button doesn't want to stretch and take up all the width. Why?* - **We found answer to this, but not the first part.**

[image: img]

Code:

```
<table border="1" width="150px">
            <tr><th colspan="2">Tvoje igre</th></tr>
            <tr><td class="row_title" align="right" width="50%">Št. iger:</td><td id="st_iger">0</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="row_title"align="right">Št. zmag:</td><td id="st_zmag">0</td></tr>
            <tr><th colspan="2">Vse igre</th></tr>
            <tr><td class="row_title" align="right">Št. iger:</td><td>0</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="row_title" align="right">Št. zmag:</td><td>0</td></tr>
            <tr><th colspan="2">Nova igra</th></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><select id="dropdown">
                <option>CSS lastnosti</option>
                <option>JavaScript funkcije</option>
            </select></td></tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"><button type="btn_nova_igra" onclick="novaIgra()">Nova igra</button></td></tr>  
            </table>
```

Comment: Do you have an external CSS file? If so, please post it. If not, you need to tell the button to stretch all the way across, by doing something like `<button style="width:100%" ...`. Also, try setting the width of the `td` using inline css as well: `<td style="width:50%" ...`. It's bad practice to use inline-css, but it helps with debugging.

Comment: I tried `style="width:50%"` but it doesn't change nothing. I have external css but nothing regarding table is currently defined there.

This happens only when I have select element in table, otherwise not.

Comment: Your code works fine for me in Firefox and IE9. Not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, Had to change some CSS properties :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you want to stretch the button? why you don't use this:

```
<button style="width: 100%;" type="btn_nova_igra" onclick="novaIgra()">Nova igra</button>
```

Comment: I've just found out, but thanks! What about table cells sizes?

Comment: your example works for me by <td width="50%" ..., if you have problem, its probably from your external css

Answer (score 2):

Since the table already has a predefined size (150px), you can force each column to size properly by explicitly setting the width on the first 2 columns as so:

```
 <tr>
      <td width="75px" class="row_title" align="right">Št. iger:</td>
      <td width="75px" id="st_iger">0</td>
 </tr>
```

This will effectively force each column to be half the size of the whole table's width.

Comment: Thank you. Others have suggested the same thing, and actually it works, I just had to set the select also to width:100%.